# Translations for Laravel 9 Email template not found by the locale

Tags: laravel

Laravel email translations in the `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.php` file, translations are retrieved using `->subject(Lang::get('Verify Email Address'))`, but if no key is specified, they are not retrieved from any file at all , takes only if specified key: `->subject(Lang::get('messages.Verify Email Address'))` - then works.

I have tried to put translation in these files, no luck:

```
`/lang/lt/messages.json`
`/lang/lt/messages.php`
`/lang/lt/app.php`
`/lang/lt/app.json`
```

In `config.php` locale, 'lt' is correctly specified. However, it does work with a key - loads from `/lang/lt/messages.php`, but doesn't when key is no specified.

/resources/lang/lt/messages.php:

```
 <?php

return [
    "E-mail" => "El. paštas",
    "Verify Email Address"=> "Patvirtinkite el. pašto adresą",
    "Please click the button below to verify your email address."=> "Prašome paspausti ant žemiau paspaustos nuorodos šio el. pašto adreso patvirtinimui.",
    "If you did not create an account, no further action is required."=> "Jei Jūs nekūrėte svetainėje sena.lt vartotojo, jokių veiksmų atlikti nereikia.",
];
```

Comment: Show me your both lang JSON and PHP file

Comment: @AbdullaNilam provided messages.php, json removed to do not confuse..

Comment: why don't you use `__()` ? Ex `__('message.verify_email_address)` and make sure array keys like this `verify_email_address` **snakeCase**

Comment: that was provided in vendors - can't change that. But I have solved the issue providing new file to /resources/lang/lt.json!

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue providing new file to /resources/lang/lt.json